# INFO serverity logger collects ERROR log messages

Tags: python

In my system I need to types of logging:

1. Execution Tracing
2. Error Fixing (with exc_info=True for tracing)

For that I've created two loggers with their own logging level (logging.ERROR and logging.INFO), handlers (distinct file for each) and specific format. It looks like this:

```
import os
import logging

LOG_PATH = 'logs'


class ErrorLogger:

    def create_logger(self, log_path):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        if not os.path.exists(LOG_PATH):
            os.makedirs(LOG_PATH)
        filepath = os.path.join(LOG_PATH, log_path)
        error_handler = logging.FileHandler(filepath)
        error_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        error_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(msg)s')
        error_handler.setFormatter(error_format)
        self.logger.addHandler(error_handler)

    def log(self, msg):
        self.logger.exception(msg, exc_info=True)


class TraceLogger:

    def create_logger(self, log_path):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        if not os.path.exists(LOG_PATH):
            os.makedirs(LOG_PATH)
        filepath = os.path.join(LOG_PATH, log_path)
        trace_handler = logging.FileHandler(filepath)
        trace_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        trace_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
        trace_handler.setFormatter(trace_format)
        self.logger.addHandler(trace_handler)

    def log(self, msg):
        self.logger.info(msg)


error = ErrorLogger()
error.create_logger('error.log')

tracer = TraceLogger()
tracer.create_logger('trace.log')
```

So, I hoped that only INFO severity messages  would be in log-file of my INFO-logger, and the same for ERROR-logger. And it's right for ERROR-logger.

But INFO-logger also collects Exception message with it's stack trace if it occures.

For example, in realization like this:

```
from logsys.exception import FirstOneException
from logsys.logger import error, tracer


def first():
    try:
        tracer.log('first')
        second()
    except BaseException as e:
        print('First def: {}'.format(e))
        raise


def second():
    try:
        tracer.log('second')
        third()
    except BaseException as e:
        print('Second def: {}'.format(e))
        raise


def third():
    try:
        tracer.log('third')
        1/0
    except BaseException as e:
        print('Third def: {}'.format(e))
        raise FirstOneException('from third def')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        first()
    except BaseException as e:
        print('error: {}'.format(e))
        error.log(e)
```

INFO-log looks like this:

> 2019-09-06 12:51:25,647 - first
>
> 2019-09-06 12:51:25,647 - second
>
> 2019-09-06 12:51:25,647 - third
>
> 2019-09-06 12:51:25,647 - FirstOneException. Listed arguments: ('from third def',).  Traceback
>
> (most recent call last):
>
> ...some stack trace

But I need only my actuall trace fixations, like this:

> 2019-09-06 12:51:25,647 - first
>
> 2019-09-06 12:51:25,647 - second
>
> 2019-09-06 12:51:25,647 - third

I found that **self.logger** is the same object in both **Log classes**, and when I call **log** *function* of Logger class it works with the same object.

But how can I then realize functionality that I need, and what is the sense of such implementation of *logging.getLogger* if it returns same object? In all tutorials I've found method getLogger uses to specify handling and formatting properties of multiple loggers, but in my case it catch errors despite of different Severity Level.

Comment: log levels have a higheracrhey. When you set the level to INFO it will show all messages with a severity of INFO or greater. ERROR messages have a higher severity than INFO so will also be logged. setting the log LEVEL to INFO does not log only INFO messages

Comment: How can I realize such distinction then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are actaully creating two references to the same logger. So you create the logger first and set everything with error related attribtues. However then you create the info logger which is just points to the same logger as the error logger and you then change all the attributes for info. So when you do error.log its actually writing but now its with the info attributes.

Below is a more generic approach to creating seperate loggers for each.

```
import logging


class MyLogger:
    def __init__(self, logger_level, log_file_name):
        logger = logging.getLogger(str(logger_level))
        logger.setLevel(logger_level)
        handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file_name)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        self.logger = logger
        self.level = logger_level

    def log(self, msg):
        self.logger.log(self.level, msg)


info_only = MyLogger(logging.INFO, "info.log")
error_only = MyLogger(logging.ERROR, "error.log")
info_only.log("This is in info message")
error_only.log("This is an error message")
info_only.log("This is another info message")
error_only.log("this is another error message")
try:
    int("a")
except ValueError as ve:
    error_only.log(ve)
```

**info.log**

```
2019-09-06 12:13:10,475 - This is in info message
2019-09-06 12:13:10,475 - This is another info message
```

**error.log**

```
2019-09-06 12:13:10,475 - This is an error message
2019-09-06 12:13:10,475 - this is another error message
2019-09-06 12:13:10,475 - invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

Comment: Thank for refactoring!)
In general my mistakes was:
1) I've instantiated logging objects in a way they were the same object (logging.getLogger(__name__)) - instead of that there should be specific name for each
2) In according with refactored code it would be better to log activity by logger.log(level, message)
tnx!

Comment: yeah when creating your two logger the `__name__` for both would be `main` so both were copies of the same logger. you could probably make this work in your original code by just giving each logger a name. But you have a lot of repeated code so better to refactor for maintanability and clean code.